# Dual boot Windows 10 firewall partitions single ssd

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, multi-boot

Dual booting a Windows 10 laptop off single disk.

How do I firewall each partition from the other ie A cannot r/w B and B cannot r/w A?

Comment: While booted into one OS, remove the drive letter from the other partition, then do the same while booted into the other OS. This will have no adverse effects.

Comment: And "firewall" in this context is quite incorrect considering that it already has a very precise connotation/usage in IT and is all about networking.

Answer (score 1):

Simple : Remove in A the drive-letter for partition B, and vice-versa
remove in B the drive-letter for A.

This is done in the Disk Management utility by right-click on the partition,
in each system.

Without a drive-letter, it's impossible for Windows to modify a disk.